# Why isn't BroadcastStream a type in Dart?

Tags: dart, stream

This is actually a serious question.  The way to create a BroadcastStream, as far as I know, is as follows:

```
StreamSubscription sc = StreamSubscription();
Stream s = Stream();
sc.addStream(s);
var bs = sc.stream.asBroadcastStream();  // this works
BroadcastStream bs = sc.stream.asBroadcastStream();  //  type error, undefined class BroadcastStream
```

Why isn't BroadcastStream a type, instead of needing to use var?  Is there actually a rationale behind it, is it a bug, or am I missing something else?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A broadcast stream has the same API as a non-broadcast stream, so it doesn't need a separate class. It simply is a `Stream`.

The way to create a broadcast stream is to either have a broadcast stream and use any of the stream transformer operations on it (like `myBroadcastStream.map(...)`) or to create the stream from scratch using a controller, `var c = StreamController.broadcast(...);`.

You can check whether a stream is a broadcast stream using `myStream.isBroadcast`.

You can see being a broadcast stream as more of a behavior choice, a strategy, than a separate type of stream. Streams can behave in many different ways using the same API. Currently we only have two behaviors, but it would be easy to create a third behavior, say a stream that can be listened to more than once, but which does not send the same events to all listeners at the same time (like an iterable that can be reused).

Comment: also take a look at the answer from @Günter Zöchbauer

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there was a strong reason for either way, but there is no need to use `var` anyway.

```
Stream bs = sc.stream.asBroadcastStream();
```

The difference between single-subscription stream and broadcast stream probably wasn't enough to warrant a distinct class.

See also https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-async/Stream/asBroadcastStream.html

Comment: brilliant solution!